# How to request same query by adding an additional header to request

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have a unique problem with SCG. I manage session cookies programatically by my self without using spring framework capability. My requirement is as follows:

I run a request which is forwarded to service, when it replies **UNAUTHORIZED** I want to intercept and send request again by refreshing session cookie. And final response to client should be forwarded after this. I tried writing my own GatewayFilterFactory but not bale to solve the problem as I am new to reactive programming.

Thanks in Advance,
agllno